# clustered index on a column which has duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with no index. I need to add a clustered index on one column but the table does not have any column having unique data.Will this allow me to add clustered index on a duplicate column?

Comment: SQL Server will add a hidden [4 byte uniqueifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190639(v=sql.105).aspx) for rows with non unique key values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A clustered index does not enforce uniqueness unless you specify the keyword UNIQUE.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX bob ON foo( bar )
```

is not the same as

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX bob on foo( bar )
```

You may be thinking of a PRIMARY KEY constraint in a CREATE TABLE statement. 
In this example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( bar PRIMARY KEY )
```

ASE will create a UNIQUE, CLUSTERED index on bar.